# Too many arguments and char[22] errors in C

Tags: c

I'm getting 2 errors at the end of this code: 1 - Too many arguments in function call and Expression must have struct or union type but it has type "char*", respectively. Where did I go wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

char soma_multipla_vetor(int vetor[], char operation) {
    int i;
    double total = 0;
    double result;
    char size;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        total = total + vetor[i];
    }
    if (operation == 'm') {
        result = total / size;

    } else {
        result = total;
    }
    return 0;

}

int main()
{
    double result;
    int i;
    int vetor[5];
    printf("Type 5 numbers\n");
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &vetor[1]);
    }
    result = soma_multipla_vetor(vetor, 5, 'm');
                                ^
    printf("The result is %.2lf.\n". result);
}          ^
```

Comment: 1. The function `soma_multipla_vetor` takes only 2 arguments, but you gave 3. 2. Typo: You should use `,` for the separator of arguments, but you used `.`.

Comment: Also the `for` loop in the `main` function looks weird because 1. The `scanf()` is reading to `vetor[1]` 6 times instead of reading for each elements of `vetor`. 2. If `vetor[1]` were `vetor[i]`, there will be out-of-range access due to the wrong condition. If you want to read only 5 elements, the condition should be `i < 5`, not `i <= 5`. If you actually want to read 6 elements,allocate (at least) 6 elements for `vetor`.

Comment: One more weird point is that the variable `result` in the function `soma_multipla_vetor` is written but never read.

Comment: Is there any way i can use the 'm' argument despite it only expecting 2 arguments?

Comment: One way is giving up to receive the size of array as an argument and use the value `5` globally in your program (for example, by defining it as a macro like `#define N 5`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `soma_multipla_vetor`, you're giving it 3 arguments:

```
result = soma_multipla_vetor(vetor, 5, 'm');
```

But it only expects 2:

```
char soma_multipla_vetor(int vetor[], char operation) {
```

You're also using `size` inside of this function without initializing it.  Presumably you wanted this to be an argument, so add it to the function definition to match how it's being called:

```
char soma_multipla_vetor(int vetor[], int size, char operation) {
```

For this line:

```
printf("The result is %.2lf.\n". result);
```

You're using the `.` operator, which only applies to a `struct`, on a string constant.  You want a `,` instead to separate the arguments:

```
printf("The result is %.2lf.\n", result);
```

You also have an issue with this code in `main`:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &vetor[1]);
}
```

You're always writing to the element with index 1 instead of using `i`.  The loop condition is also incorrect as it should be using `<` instead of `<=`.

Comment: Thanks, everything is solved except result = soma_multipla_vetor(vetor, 5, 'm'); how am I supposed to use the 'm' argument when it expects only 2 arguments? ('m' is primordial for the code to function)

Comment: @TiagoAndrade As specified above, the function is changed to accept 3 arguments.  Also, you want to return the value of `result` instead of 0.